# How to add translation to opencart text strings?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.3

I'm using Opencart v2.3.0.2.
Need help in how to translate some text strings. I've added some links to my header menu (in /catalog/view/theme/mytheme/template/common/header.tpl) using code :

```
<ul class="static_links">
  <li class="head-links">
    <a href="<?php echo $about_products; ?>">
      <?php echo $text_products; ?>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="head-links">
    <a href="<?php echo $contact; ?>">
      <?php echo $text_novosti; ?>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="head-links">
    <a href="<?php echo $contact; ?>">
      <?php echo $text_onas; ?>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Also I've added new strings and translations in footer.php (/catalog/language/ru-ru/common/footer.php):

```
$_['text_products'] = 'О продуктах'; $_['$text_novosti'] = 'Новости'; $_['$text_onas'] = 'О нас';
```

Finally I've registered that translations in header.php (/catalog/controller/common/header.php):

```
//New links in menu
$data['text_products']  = $this->language->get('text_products');
$data['text_novosti']  = $this->language->get('text_novosti');        
$data['text_onas']  = $this->language->get('text_onas');
```

After all when I open page with menu it shows only translation texts for `$text_products`. In other places it shows only value `text_novosti` and `text_onas`. But in should show translations from footer.php instead.

Please help me, how to display translations correctly?

Or maybe there is a way to hardcode texts based on language? Something like:

```
<?php if ($lang='en') {?> <a href="#">News</a><a href="#">About us</a>
<?php } ?>
```

НовостиО нас

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use your strings in header.tpl, then you must add your strings to:

```
catalog/language/ru-ru/common/header.php
```

not to:

```
catalog/language/ru-ru/common/footer.php
```

If you want to hardcode, in `header.php` add:

```
$data['lang_id'] = $this->config->get('config_language_id');
```

And in `header.tpl`:

```
<?php if ($lang_id == 1) {?>
    <a href="#">News</a>
    <a href="#">About us</a>
<?php } else if ($lang_id == 2) {?>
    <a href="#">Новости</a>
    <a href="#">О нас</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the mistake was in this string `$_['text_products'] = 'О продуктах'; $_['$text_novosti'] = 'Новости'; $_['$text_onas'] = 'О нас';` I've placed unnecessary `$`.